# How to add a precompiled header in xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11.3, pch

I wanted to define few custom values in a `pre-compiled header` for different targets of my app. I tried the following to define headers, but none worked:

1. by adding a header from `Editor -> Add Build Setting -> Add User Defined setting` and assign key value pair.
2. Set `Preprocess info.plist` file to YES in `Build Settings` and set the header (.h) file in `Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix file`.

How do I add and set a pch key so that I can set `true` for UAT target and `false` for Production target using #if ?

Answer (score 1):

If the sole purpose is to set different values for different environments - `development, QA, UAT, Production`, the `xcconfig` files can be used.

No conditional statements would be required but based on the configuration, it will take the appropriate values.

Steps involved would be:

1. Add different Schema and different build Configurations.
2. Add Configuration Settings file by selecting File->New->File and `"Configuration Settings file"` -> `Development.xcconfig, UAT.xcconfig, Production.xcconfig` etc

[image]

3. Add custom keys of your choice in the config file and their relevant values in Key-Value pair as:

   `endpointUrl = "Production_Url"` for Production.xcconfig

   `endpointUrl = "UAT_Url"` for UAT.xcconfig

[image]

4. Add relevant plist files and mention the keys from .xcconfig file to the .plist file. Create UAT.plist for UAT.xcconfig file and similar way for other supported configs.

[image]

5. Set the appropriate plist path for each build configuration under `Project -> Info -> Configurations`

[image]

6. Create a .swift file to read the config file such as:

> public enum PlistKey {
>       case EndpointURL
>
> ```
> func value() -> String {
>     switch self {
>     case .EndpointURL:
>         return "endpointUrl"
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> public struct Environment {
>
> ```
>     fileprivate var infoDict: [String: Any]  {
>         get {
>             if let dict = Bundle.main.infoDictionary {
>                 return dict
>             }else {
>                 fatalError("Plist file not found")
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     public func configuration(_ key: PlistKey) -> String {
>         switch key {
>         case .EndpointURL:
>             return infoDict[PlistKey.EndpointURL.value()] as? String ?? "noValue"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

7. Call the url as:

> `let server_url = Environment().configuration(PlistKey.EndpointURL)`

More detailed version at: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/managing-different-environments-and-configurations-for-ios-projects-7970327dd9c9/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift. Then you can add custom swift flags. Under Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Custom Flags.

and then in code use

```
#if YourFlag
....
#else
```